# What implementation of cycle is better?

Tags: c#, .net

I wonder, what implementation is better from reading and performance sides.
1)

```
for (DateTime
         dayStart = GetDayStart(today),
         dayEnd = GetDayEnd(today);
     dayStart < endOfPeriod;
     dayStart = dayStart.AddDays(1), dayEnd = dayEnd.AddDays(1))
{
    // ...
}
```

2)

```
DateTime dayStart = GetDayStart(today),
         dayEnd = GetDayEnd(today);

while (dayStart < endOfPeriod)
{
    // ...
    dayStart = dayStart.AddDays(1);
    dayEnd = dayEnd.AddDays(1);
}
```

3) Or, may be any another?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Both of these look unattractive to me.

Comment: I want to iterate by single-day intervals, starting from current date to `endOfPeriod`

Comment: what is `EndOfPeriod`? `GetDayEnd()`? `GetDayStart()`?  It seems like you're abstracting something that shouldn't need to be abstracted.

Comment: @Jeremy yes he is, the function and variable names are clear enough, and his sole question is about readability. Performance shouldn't differ between the two.

Comment: @CodeCaster that is not the thrust of my question... He has a 3) listed, remember?  I'm concerned that I can't figure out what this is supposed to do or how it should be used as written, so I'm wondering, from a readability and performance standpoint, if a good deal of this is superfluous.  I'd like some more clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For readability I would go with the second choise. The `for` statement is great for simpler loops, but it gets harder to follow when it gets more complicated.

For performance there should be no difference at all. The compiler will likely produce the exact same code from the two different source codes.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I find the second one the most readable. Multiple statements in a for-loop are more error-prone and less clear to an objective reader of your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you looking for minor variations of your approach you could also look at using Timespan...

```
        DateTime dayStart = GetDayStart(today);
        TimeSpan days = GetDayEnd(today) - dayStart;
        while (dayStart < endOfPeriod)
        {
            DateTime dayEnd = dayStart.Add(days);

            // ...
            dayStart = dayStart.AddDays(1);
        }
```

Only reason I like this more is because I didn't like the fact you had to increment both dates.